# waitForNavigation hanging for no reason

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I try to click the `next page` button to iterate different pages, but after `click`, the script hangs there forever, code as below.

Why `waitForNavigation` never finishes?

```
async function main() {
  const br = await pptr.launch({headless: false, defaultViewport: null});
  const page = await br.newPage();

  await page.goto(
    'https://www.escentual.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=face',
    {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}
  );

  for (var i=0; i<10; ++i) {   // click next-page button 10 times,
    await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 100000}),
      page.click('#adj-nav-container > div.category-products > div.toolbar > div > div.amount > div > ol > li.next > a'),  // next-page css
    ]);
    console.log(`waited, url=${page.url()}`);
  }
  await br.close();
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a overlay on top of the element you're trying to click. You should either close that overlay or just use the `HTMLElement.click`:

```js
page.$eval('#adj-nav-container > div.category-products > div.toolbar > div > div.amount > div > ol > li.next > a', el => el.click())
```

Alternatively, you can just change the page number in the website's URL:

```
https://www.escentual.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?p=1&q=face
https://www.escentual.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?p=2&q=face
...
```

---

#### Detecting overlay

Here is one way of detecting whether the element is behind an overlay. [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) gets a coordinate and returns the topmost element of that coordinate. We get the selected element's coordinate with [`boundingBox()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#elementhandleboundingbox) method, and then compare it with the top most element of that coordinate. If they're the same, it means the element is not behind an overlay or another element.

Example:

```js
let targetElement = await page.$('#adj-nav-container > div.category-products > div.toolbar > div > div.amount > div > ol > li.next > a');
let {x, y} = await targetElement.boundingBox();

let isOnTop = await page.evaluate((x,y, selectedElement) => {
    let topElement = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    return topElement === selectedElement;
}, x, y, targetElement);

if (isOnTop)
    console.log("Element is not behind overlay");
```

Comment: How could I find out there is an overlay?

Comment: And why would the overlay affect the link click?

Comment: Puppeteer's mouse click hovers over the center of element and emulates a mouse click. so if there is an overlay on the element or the element is not visible it won't click.

Comment: added the overlay detection to the answer